# Find radius and center of circle that is tangent to two axes and another circle

Tags: geometry

Circle 1's center is located at (x1, y1) and it has a radius of R1. How would I calculate the location of the center (x2, y2) and radius R2 of circle 2 if circle 2 were to lie tangent to the x-axis, y-axis, and circle 1?

[image]

Comment: Hints: What’s the distance between the two centers? Where do the centers of circles tangent to the coordinate axes lie?

Comment: Must the circle be externally tangent, as you’ve drawn it? The problem statement as you have it doesn’t specify this, so there are other possibilities.

Comment: You know that $R_2 = x_{2} = y_{2}$ and that $\sqrt{(x_{1}-x_{2})^{2}+(y_{1}-y_{2})^{2}} = R_{1} + R_{2}$

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The distance from the center to the x-axis, from the center to the y-axis, and from the center to the other circle all equal.

So $x_2=y_2=d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))-r_1$